# Using razor pages annotations in page model

Tags: asp.net, data-annotations, razor-pages

I have been using data annotations just fine, however I am now trying to specify one directly in a page model. Usually I create an object model and specify the validation requirements there, however as this is only a single string I didn't see the point.

In card.cshtml.cs

```
 public class CardModel : PageModel
 {

    [BindProperty, StringLength(200, MinimumLength=5, ErrorMessage = "Please enter a note")]
    public String Note { get; set; }


     public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostNoteAsync(int? id)
    {
        //Do stuff

        return RedirectToPage(new { ID });
    }
```

In card.cshtml:

```
            <div class="justify-content-center">
                <form asp-page-handler="note" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value=@Model.Card.Id />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Note" class="control-label">
                            <i class="fas fa-1x fa-comment-dots pr-2"></i>
                            New Note
                        </label>
                        <textarea asp-for="Note" class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Note" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" id="card-form" style="text-align: right">                            
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-ver-blue">
                            <span class="text">Add Note</span>
                        </button>

                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>
```

Unfortunately, the form submits just fine when empty without throwing a validation error.

Comment: looks like you have added wrong annotations please refer to this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/model-validation-using-data-annotations-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: I have tired [BindProperty, Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a note between 5 and 200 characters"), MinLength(5), MaxLength(200)] but still no luck

Comment: have you compaire your `cshtml`  with the one in the tutorial. your's doesn't seem to follow razor syntax.

Comment: Which one? The cshtml.cs is edited to just show the relevant parts, but the bottom one is correct. It all works but it doesn't show the validation.

Comment: Have you included the unobtrusive validation library in the page, and do you test ModelState where it says `// do stuff` in the named handler method? Does the handler even get hit, since it doesn't appear to follow naming convention? (or is that a typo in the question?)

Comment: Yes, I forgot to include the validation script at the bottom of the page. I have also corrected the typo in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes :)